# typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') while calling the api(own) in useffect hook in ReactJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am calling my own api for fetching all messages form the data base.

```
const {messages, setMessages} = useState([]);
    // we will call the api to get all message of the currentChat. and whenver the currentChat is changing we will call the api
    useEffect(() =>{
        async function fetchMsg(){
                console.log(currentChat)
                console.log(currentUser);
                const response = await axios.post(getAllMessagesRoute, {
                    from: currentUser._id,
                    to:currentChat._id,
                })
                
                setMessages(response.data);
        }
        fetchMsg();
    }, [currentChat]);
```

I want that whenever the `currentChat` is changing, the `useEffect` should be called. Both the above `console.log()` showing correct `currentChat` and `currentUser` but it is still showing `_id` is not defined. see the below error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')
    at fetchMsg (ChatContainer.js:19:1)
    at ChatContainer.js:25:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:26769:1
```

Comment: currentUser or currentChat does not have _id

Comment: so what does `console.log(currentUser);` print?

Comment: It has the _id properties but still it is showing _id is not defined